# Construct a regular grammar that produces all possible strings of $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ that do not contain substring 'abba'

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I'm really stuck here and do not know what to do. So far, I've constructed a DFA and a regular expression that produces the aforementioned set of strings. Namely, the DFA looks like: [image]

After a lot of efforts I managed to find a concise regular expression of it, namely:
$$ b^*\left( a + (b \; | \;  bbb+)\right)^*a^*b^*.$$

What I have tried so far as to construct the desired regular grammar is:
\begin{align*}
q_0 &\rightarrow b \ | \ a \ | \ aq_1 | \ ε \ \\
q_1 &\rightarrow aq_1 \ | \ bq_2 \ | \ ε \ \\
q_2 &\rightarrow aq_0 \ | \ bq_3 \ | \ ε \ \\ 
q_3 &\rightarrow bq_0 \ | \ aq_4 \ | \ ε 
\end{align*}

Obviously $q_4$ is non-yielding, therefore we can omit it, and we get

\begin{align*}
q_0 &\rightarrow b \ | \ a \ | \ aq_1 | \ ε \ \\
q_1 &\rightarrow aq_1 \ | \ bq_2 \ | \ ε \ \\
q_2 &\rightarrow aq_0 \ | \ bq_3 \ | \ ε \ \\ 
q_3 &\rightarrow bq_0 \  | \ ε 
\end{align*}

Correct me if I'm wrong but the above rules as is, define a context free grammar since we have more than one non-Terminal symbol on the right side. How can I turn the above rules into a regular grammar? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That already is a [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar); in particular, it is right-regular.